# loading images from url in json to listview

Tags: android, json

I'd like to load images from json data which contains the url to these images into a listview,,,
the class implementing the json data has the following code:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mylist = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
    //JSONfunctions j1 = new JSONfunctions();
    JSONObject j2=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("/newwebsite/apis/index.php?device=iphone&api=store_list");
    try{JSONArray myID=j2.getJSONArray("stores");
        //JSONArray mc = json.getJSONArray("mc");   

        for(int i=0;i<myID.length();i++){
            Log.v("state","json data being read");
            JSONObject j3= myID.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = j3.getString("StoreTitle");
            JSONObject j4= myID.getJSONObject(i);
            //String name2 = j4.getString("StoreLogo");
            String imgurl = j4.getString("StoreLogo");
            //map.put("img",+StoreLogo);
            //URL newurl = new URL(j4.getString("StoreLogo"));

            String name1 = j4.getString("Address");

            Log.v("Address",name1);
            Log.v("Storetitle",name);
            HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();

            JSONObject im = myID.getJSONObject(i);


            map.put("Id",String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("Storename","Store"+j3.getString("StoreTitle"));
            //map.put("img","http"+j3.getString("StoreLogo") );

            mylist.add(map);
        }}
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("loG_tag","Error parsing"+e.toString());
        }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.mclist);
   // WebAdapter jAdap=new WebAdapter(context);

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,mylist,R.layout.custom_row_view1,
        new String[] {"Storename","add","img"},
        new int[] {R.id.mCname,R.id.mCcity,R.id.mClogo});
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and the json data is in the format

```
{"error":false,"totalresults":8,"stores":[{"StoreId":"38","StoreTitle":"Young & Jacksons","StoreLogo":"http:\/\/pocketdocket.com.au\/newwebsite\/uploads\/store\/1330635669night-young-and-jacksons-billboard.jpg","
```

where StoreLogo is the url to the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u have loading the image json parsing. u have use image loader.

Imageloader.java class

```
public class ImageLoader {

    //the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private File cacheDir;

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        //Find the dir to save cached images
       if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }        
        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {

        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            DataInputStream input = null;
        //    InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
            String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(("devneoauto" + ":" + "2kk0rnpnpvir")
                 .getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getmethod = new HttpGet(url);

            getmethod.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
            getmethod.addHeader("X-ZFWS-Accept", "text/json");

            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(getmethod);
            HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();

            if (resEntityGet != null) {

                input = new DataInputStream(responseGet.getEntity().getContent());

            }

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(input, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale++;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        if(((String)photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
           else
               imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.stub);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache
        cache.clear();        
        //clear SD cache
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

This class use by this method 
    imageloader.DisplayImage(UserSearchResponse.Book_image2.get(position), Book.this, Bookphoto);

```
where UsersearchResponse.Book.get(position) use for image url pasrsing for json 
Book.this for where this Activity in class for example Book is class 
    Bookphoto for where this is ImageView
```

I m sure this code help u

Comment: Do I need to make a separate adapter class to implement this or the listadapter itslf is enough ?

Comment: listadapter itself enough, dear friends