# Create a picture on Android

Tags: android, drawable, image

I want to create a picture to send a website on android. But It must be background.. let me explain more..

[the picture is what i want http://e1203.hizliresim.com/v/r/3s06c.png](http://e1203.hizliresim.com/v/r/3s06c.png)

I have some photo which I want to put on the main picture. and I'll write some text near of photos.. and will create (draw)a big main photo.. But It must process background..

I think that I need to use drawing but I dont have any idea how can I create like that picture..

I hope I could explain my problem..

Comment: i hope this link clear your problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835228/loading-images-from-url-in-json-to-listview/9835366#9835366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`Canvas` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html):

You need to do something like this:

```
class Panel extends View {
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(...);
        canvas.drawText(...);
    }
}
```

Look at [this tutorial](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) for details.